# DateTime object not accepting dd/MM/yyyy format ASP.NET Core Web API and C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, datetime, datetime-format

I have a `DateTime` query parameter in an ASP.NET Core Web API, if I pass it a date with `dd/MM/yyyy` format, I get an error "invalid value".

Actually, on the front end, I am using Blazor WASM and it's sending the value in the `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

For now, I have to use string type and keep it formatted as `MM/dd/yyyy` or `yyyy/MM/dd` for API to accept. is there any other solution? I Want to use DateTime and not string can i get `yyyy/MM/dd` format from DateTime without converting it to string?

**API Endpoint**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] DateTime date)
{
  return Ok(date);
}
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: @PMF question updated. Thanks

Comment: i recommend using the ISO-date format - or explicitly _specifying_ the format. after all: how else should the program recognise if with `12/11/2022` you mean the 12th of november or the 11th of december? also: please include code, error messages, and other _text-based_ information ***as text***, [not as screenshot](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: @FranzGleichmann sorry i was not clear in my question. I have updated the question. What I want is to keep DateTime instead of string but DateTime is sending value in invalid format `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: then you should include the client code that's actually sending the data. also: check the culture settings on your client and server and compare them.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Thanks it's the issue of culture settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use long data type for the DateTime exchange. This is Unix time which is UTC. Easy to exchange DateTime between server and client.

From the javascript client-side you can get Unix time like this.

```
var d = new Date();
var ut = d.getTime();
```

From the asp.net server

```
var ut = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```